# How to subset data using multiple characters in a column

Tags: r, subset, dataformat

This is a very simple question.

I have a lengthy dataset and want to create a subset based on certain entries in a particular column. In this case, I am setting it up like this:

Example data:

```
> NL

SNP alleles

rs1234 A_T

rs1235 A_G

rs2343 A_T

rs2342 G_C

rs1134 C_G

rs1675 T_A

rs8543 A_T

rs2842 G_A

P <- subset(NL, alleles = "A_T", alleles = "T_A", alleles = "G_C", alleles = "C_G")
```

This runs without error, but the resulting P is not subset in any way (tail of P still shows same number of entries as original NL).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want your `subset` to be the alleles `in` the `vector` `c('A_T','T_A','G_C','C_G')`?  P.S. that's a riddle of hints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most obvious error is using "=" when you mean"==". But I'm guessing from context that you really want to "split" this data:

```
split(NL, NL$alleles)
```

Which will create a list of dataframes each of which has one of the values for `alleles`.

But perhaps you do want to use pattern matching:

```
NL[ grepl("C_G|G_C|A_T|T_A", NL$alleles), ]
     SNP alleles
1 rs1234     A_T
3 rs2343     A_T
4 rs2342     G_C
5 rs1134     C_G
6 rs1675     T_A
7 rs8543     A_T
```

And illustrating with what I think was your comment-example:

```
P <- read.table(text="V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 alleles
 15116 25 rsX 0 123412 G A G_A 
15117 25 rsX1 0 23432 A C A_C 
15118 25 rsX2 0 234324 A G A_G 
15119 25 rsX3 0 3423 A G A_G 
15120 25 rsX4 0 2343223 C A C_A 
15121 25 rsX5 0 23523423 A G A_G", header=TRUE)

 P[ grepl("G_A", NL$alleles), ]

#       V1       V2 V3        V4 V5 V6 alleles
# 15116 25 rs306910  0 154613671  G  A     G_A
```

The subset version:

```
 subset(P, alleles %in% c("G_A", "A_G") )

      V1   V2 V3       V4 V5 V6 alleles
15116 25  rsX  0   123412  G  A     G_A
15118 25 rsX2  0   234324  A  G     A_G
15119 25 rsX3  0     3423  A  G     A_G
15121 25 rsX5  0 23523423  A  G     A_G
```

Comment: Using == gives me the following error:   **Error in `[.data.frame`(x, r, vars, drop = drop) : 
  object 'alleles' not found** But, I can work with split. Thanks!

Comment: @user1224314 If that's the case then there's something different about the data you provided in your question, and the data you're working with on your machine. We can only help based on the example data you provided.

Comment: @user1224314 Make sure that your `NL` object is a data frame, and that the name of the alleles column is `"alleles"`. You can use `str(NL)` to see what structure it has, and `names(NL)` to look at the column names.

Comment: @user1224314 You haven't combined `==` with the other corrections provided to you in other comments and answers. The `==` wasn't the only thing wrong. Try fixing all the issues raised by the folks here before trying again.

Comment: Despite the lack of formatting in my comment post, you heard me. I wasn't aware that grep could be used in R. This works - thank you!

Comment: Oh, yes, grepping is very well used in R although notice that I used `grepl` which I find safer for selection. It does not depend for its validity on the default rownames for dataframes. Look also at `?grep`, `?regex` and `?strsplit`

Answer (score 0):

`=` is used for passing arguments or for assignment. What you need is is to test whether something is true, use `==`. You're also passing multiple criteria and not specifying how the should be combined. I'm pretty sure you want the subset where *any* of those conditions are true (not *all*), but R doesn't. For this case, you can use the `%in%` operator:

```
P <- subset(NL, alleles %in% c("A_T", "T_A", "C_G"))
```

Also notice that you're trying to give `subset` several conditions, but you're not telling it how to combine them. I can see that you're want the rows where any of the conditions are true, but you have to tell R that using the OR operator, `|`, e.g.

```
P <- subset(NL, alleles == "A_T" | alleles == "T_A" | alleles == "C_G")
```

The `%in%` operator above is like a shorthand for this.